# String.format decimal with fixed width, zero padded and no decimal separator

Tags: java, spring-batch, formatter

I have a double (e.g: 123.45) and I need generate a string like 0000012345.

I'm trying to do it using only String.format ([Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)). I could use DecimalFormat and then replaceAll, but I was wondering if I could achieve the same result using formatter. **The reason is that I will use it with FormatterLineAggregator (spring batch)**.

***[EDIT] - Emphasis on the question reason. Tagged as spring batch also. Included link to spring batch documentation.***

From Spring Batch doc: "... The underlying implementation is built using the same Formatter added as part of Java 5. The Java Formatter is based on the printf functionality of the C programming language. Most details on how to configure a formatter can be found in the javadoc of Formatter.".

[Spring Batch itemWriter link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemWriter)

Comment: You could use DecimalFormat *without* 'replaceAll()'. Why the fixation on 'String.format()'?

Comment: @EJP Just read que question. It's clearly stated that is because spring batch requires it. From it's manual: "The underlying implementation is built using the same Formatter added as part of Java 5. The Java Formatter is based on the printf functionality of the C programming language. Most details on how to configure a formatter can be found in the javadoc of Formatter".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Batch : PassThroughFieldExtractor with BigDecimal formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407486/spring-batch-passthroughfieldextractor-with-bigdecimal-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Could you stash the value into a `Formattable` and use [`Formattable#formatTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html#formatTo%28java.util.Formatter,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to generate the desired output?

As far as I know there's no way to suppress the decimal separator in a standard `String.format("%f")` output. Even if you add a `DecimalFormatSymbolsProvider` class, it must still return a `char` value from [`DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getDecimalSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getDecimalSeparator%28%29).