# How to output complex attribute using Spring Btch DelimitedAggregator

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I want to process XML document and output comma delimited output.
I'm using Spring Batch per this link - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#xmlReadingWriting

Specifically, I used StaxEventItemReader to read in the XML and use FlatFileItemWriter for writing configured with DelimitedLineAggregator.

The issue I am having is that the "fieldExtractor" bean BeanWrapperFieldExtractor, will output
primitive attribute (i.e primitive value String, int, etc).  Some of my attributes are of
complex types.  So with this in-the-box fieldExtractor, I can only print the object pointer
which is not useful.

This post suggests extension of DelimitedLineAggregator to modify the field value - [Spring Batch : PassThroughFieldExtractor with BigDecimal formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407486/spring-batch-passthroughfieldextractor-with-bigdecimal-formatting)

It looks like I have to do this, and plug in a service for each of the "complex" field.
This service will have to "recursively" loop through the field object to generate the
comma separated string.

How does this sound? Any working recursive algorithm you can share?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Thank you Luca. Here are the samples of input and desired output (not accurate to the tee)

https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo&authuser=2#folders/0BxTBknojMmSVTkJ0TVp5YXg4cjg

Comment: may you post a sample of input and desiderable output?

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe you shound better use a custom class to extends the FieldExtractor instead of the DelimitedLineAggregator.

According to spring it's this class which have to convert an object to small parts that can be convert to string. And it's better if you want to control the order of the field.

FieldExtractor :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FieldExtractor.html